# How to locate memory address in register $esp

Tags: assembly, x86, disassemblers, gcc

```
000011d9 <main>:
11d9:       8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
11dd:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
11e0:       ff 71 fc                push   -0x4(%ecx)
11e3:       55                      push   %ebp
11e4:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
11e6:       53                      push   %ebx
11e7:       51                      push   %ecx
11e8:       83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
11eb:       e8 f0 fe ff ff          call   10e0 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
11f0:       81 c3 10 2e 00 00       add    $0x2e10,%ebx
11f6:       c7 45 ef 49 41 32 32    movl   $0x32324149,-0x11(%ebp)
```

Comment: the answer also stated using GDB or any debugger so it is easy to lookup what esp is by querying the register  and it shouldn't matter what the actual address of esp is  it is like a hotel room you pay for the time you stay  and you may get room 102 or room 704  edit your question to state what is the actual problem you are trying to solve or understand

Comment: Hi, I re-wrote my question so it's more clear. Thanks!

Comment: i don't think a compiler will emit -0x11(%ebp) is that a randomly typed instruction  and you are still not clear what calculation you want to perform ? that last instruction is a store instruction it stores the constant "22AI" in some place

Comment: Seriously thank you so much! I tried to explain It better in another comment but I'm new to this website also and I'm not sure where things get posted

Comment: Also would you mind explaining how you determined It was a store instruction and specifically the value 22AI? Really sorry if that is a waste of time for you

Comment: don't have to be sorry it is only expected that you think and formulate a clear query [0x32 = "2" 0x32 ="2" 0x41 = "A" 0x49 ="I"](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~tway/resources/ascii-table.html)

Comment: Well really thank you for your time :)

Comment: well now you have edited your question so much that it does not make sense it is just a dump of some disassembly without a query either delete it completely or edit it with strike through and update or post a self answer

Comment: Oh I didnt do that on purpose sorry! Ill see if i can get the text back. (Also I'm looking at the table and isnt 32 an R? I'm confused)

Comment: Edit: It was a 2, I'm just dumb. But thats not the right password :(( thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching it wrong, the problem is the memory of esp can't be known before you run the program because the value is always random at the runtime so you can't know for sure the real register `esp` value until you run it.

The `esp` is only need to store the top of your program stack. So i don't think the actual value is neccessary because most of the time we only care about the offset from `esp`.